# ArrayList<String> in PDF from a new row

Tags: java, spring, pdf, itext

I want to send some survey in PDF from java, I tryed different methods. I use with  `StringBuffer` and without, but always see text in PDF in one row.

```
    public void writePdf(OutputStream outputStream) throws Exception {

    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);

    document.open();

    document.addTitle("Survey PDF");

    ArrayList nameArrays = new ArrayList();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    int i = -1;

    for (String properties : textService.getAnswer()) {

        nameArrays.add(properties);
        i++;
    }
    for (int a= 0; a<=i; a++){
        System.out.println("nameArrays.get(a) -"+nameArrays.get(a));
        sb.append(nameArrays.get(a));

    }
    paragraph.add(sb.toString());
    document.add(paragraph);

    document.close();
}
```

`textService.getAnswer()` this - `ArrayList<String>`

- Could you please advise how to separate the text in order each new sentence will be starting from new row?

Now I see like this:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the newline character `\n` and your code seems a bit overcomplicated.
Try this:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

for (String property : textService.getAnswer()) {
    sb.append(property);
    sb.append('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
nameArrays.add(properties+"\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

You *might* be able to fix that by simply appending "\n" to the strings that you collecting in your list; but I think: that very much depends on the PDF library you are using.

You see, "newlines" or "paragraphs" are to a certain degree about **formatting**. It seems like a conceptual problem to add that "formatting" information to the data that you are processing.

Meaning: you might want to check if your library allows you to provide strings - and then have the library do the formatting for you!

In other words: instead of giving strings with newlines; you should check if you can keep using strings without newlines, but if there is way to have the PDF library add line breaks were appropriate.

Side note on code quality: you are using **raw** types:

```
ArrayList nameArrays = new ArrayList();
```

should better be

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
```

[ I also changed the name - there is no point in putting the type of a collection into the variable name! ]

Answer (score 0):

This method is for save values in array list into a pdf document. In the mfilePath variable  "/" in here you can give folder name. As a example "/example/".

and also for mFileName variable you can use name. I give the date and time that document will created. don't give static name other vice your values are overriding in same pdf.

private void savePDF()
    {

```
    com.itextpdf.text.Document mDoc = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();

    String mFileName = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS", Locale.getDefault()).format(System.currentTimeMillis());

    String mFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + mFileName  + ".pdf";


    try
    {
        PdfWriter.getInstance(mDoc, new FileOutputStream(mFilePath));

        mDoc.open();

        for(int d = 0; d < g; d++)
        {
            String mtext = answers.get(d);

            mDoc.add(new Paragraph(mtext));

        }

        mDoc.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some explanation to your code, that's an important part on this platform. Our guide [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) might be helpful. Below you answer is a link `edit` to add some text. Thanks!